# "expecting a colon" where clause

Tags: apex, custom-object, code

As you see that I'm calling `doQuery()` and I'm instantiating object and creating a record and as soon it creates a record I'm getting the `ID` and once I got the `ID` I'm querying again to get the `Name` of the `Work Order` in this case the name is Auto Number.

If I tried with `:currentWorkOrderId` I'm getting the following

`select Name from Work_Order__c where Id = :tmpVar1`

```
public String currentWorkOrderId {get; set;}

public void doQuery()
{
  //insert into WO
  Work_Order__c wo = new Work_Order__c();
  wo.Est_Hours__c = 89;
  wo.Instructions__c = 'this is a test';
  insert wo;                    

  //get the inserted ID      
  currentWorkOrderId = wo.id;

  //get the Name (Auto Number) of the Work Order  
  Work_Order__c wo_obj = [select Name from Work_Order__c where Id = currentWorkOrderId]; //<<<<ERROR
   String WO_Name = wo_obj.Name;
}
```

Comment: This: Work_Order__c wo_obj should be: Work_Order__c[] wo_obj or List<Work_Orer__c> wo_obj. You don't have a `LIMIT` clause in the query.

Comment: There is an idea to use actual variable names in the debug log here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hz3PAAQ

Comment: @abu hamzah did my answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be correct.

```
Work_Order__c wo_obj = [select Name from Work_Order__c where Id =: currentWorkOrderId];
```

You need to add the `:` when you're using a variable.

You're seeing `select Name from Work_Order__c where Id = :tmpVar1` in the debug log? I believe that's normal. Is the query not working othewise with the colon in place?